# rsnapshot / cp-al: duplicate files on mounted NFS share

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, debian-wheezy, rsnapshot

### The Scenario

I'm backing up one of my Debian wheezy machines via rsnapshot. The target directory is a mounted NFS share. A Qnap NAS serves this target directory.

### The Problem

But rsnapshot complains about some file already existing, when it tries to create a new snapshot via cp -al. It doesn't matter if i use gnu-cp or rsnapshot's cp:

```
root@shuttle:~# rsnapshot -v daily
echo 25852 > /var/run/rsnapshot.pid 
/bin/rm -rf /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.6/ 
mv /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.5/ /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.6/ 
mv /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.4/ /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.5/ 
mv /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.3/ /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.4/ 
mv /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.2/ /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.3/ 
mv /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.1/ /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.2/ 
native_cp_al("/mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.0", \
    "/mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.1") 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
rsnapshot encountered an error! The program was invoked with these options:
/usr/bin/rsnapshot -v daily 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Warning! "/mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.1/shuttle/etc/alternatives/Mail.1.gz" exists!
ERROR: Warning! copy_symlink("/mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.0/shuttle/etc/alternatives/Mail.1.gz", "/mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.1/shuttle/etc/alternatives/Mail.1.gz")
[-- snip! --]
```

### The Twist

The fun thing is: The file that is giving rsnapshot (or cp -al) a hard time actually exists twice! Look at the inodes at the beginning of the line. Here's the output of `ls -li` on my Debian Box:

```
lennart@shuttle:~$ ls -li /mnt/backup/rsnapshot/daily.0/shuttle/etc/alternatives/ |grep -i mail
71047301 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  23 Oct 28 09:32 mail -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
71047299 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  23 Oct 28 09:32 Mail -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
71047302 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Oct 28 09:32 mail.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz
71047300 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Oct 28 09:32 Mail.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz
71047300 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Oct 28 09:32 Mail.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz
71047303 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  23 Oct 28 09:32 mailx -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
71047304 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  39 Oct 28 09:32 mailx.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz
```

Here's the same `ls -l1` executed on the server that is exporting the directory:

```
[~] # ls -li /share/backup/rsnapshot/daily.0/shuttle/etc/alternatives/ |grep ->
71047299 lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        23 Oct 28 09:32 Mail -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
71047300 lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        39 Oct 28 09:32 Mail.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz@
71047301 lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        23 Oct 28 09:32 mail -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
71047302 lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        39 Oct 28 09:32 mail.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz@
71047303 lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        23 Oct 28 09:32 mailx -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
71047304 lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        39 Oct 28 09:32 mailx.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz@
```

### The Question

Does anyone have any ideas what could have caused this and how to solve it?

### [edit 1]

the same ls from a machine running OS X 10.9:

```
thebook-wlan:~ lennart$ ls -li /Volumes/backup/rsnapshot/daily.0/shuttle/etc/alternatives/ |grep -i mail
71047299 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel   23 28 Okt 09:32 Mail -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
71047300 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel   39 28 Okt 09:32 Mail.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz
71047301 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel   23 28 Okt 09:32 mail -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
71047302 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel   39 28 Okt 09:32 mail.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz
71047303 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel   23 28 Okt 09:32 mailx -> /usr/bin/heirloom-mailx
71047304 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel   39 28 Okt 09:32 mailx.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.gz
```

Only my Debian box seems to have problems with the directory listing.

Comment: I actually have this exact same problem, except I `ls -li` shows everything to be completely normal for me. I've tried a bunch of different things, including remounting, blowing away the entire  backup and starting again, etc. Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this exact same problem with just once file!  My problem was that this particular file existed both as part lowercase and part uppercase.  I solved my problem by copying the uppercase file with the same name just adding 2 to the filename so:

xt_CONNMARK.ko (listed twice with the same inode)
copied to xt_CONNMARK2.ko

now xt_CONNMARK.ko is listed once along with the newly copied file, xt_CONNMARK2.ko listed once also!

Very very strange behaviour but solved?